# Why Joomla 2.5.3 says "Joomla! is up-to-date"

Tags: joomla, themes, joomla2.5

I have Joomla 2.5 website where I am using [Nano theme from yootheme](http://www.yootheme.com/themes). When I see on control panel, I  always see that **Joomla! 2.5.3**, however the latest version for 2.5 is 2.5.7.

Why I don't see the update info like I see for other themes?

How could I update 2.5.3 to 2.5.7?

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to tell you that, to specific/isolated. I suggest you get in touch with Yootheme's support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla itself helped me...

Followed **Step 2b** from [**here**](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_from_an_existing_version).

Answer (score 1):

When did you install Joomla! and did you do any automatic updates till 2.5.3? I really doubt that is had something to do with the theme.

You can manually update Joomla! to 2.5.8, check the [Joomla! 2.5.8 release page.](http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5470-joomla-2-5-8-released.html).

Of couse don't forget to backup everything before upgrading.